# How to include selenium chrome image (selenium/standalone-chrome) to bitbucket pipeline YAML file?

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to run selenium script (Java, Maven & Selenium) in bitbucket pipeline. Can you please let me know how to include selenium/standalone-chrome images to YAML file ?

```
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
default:
- step:
name: Code is pushed - Ready for Execution
script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
- echo "Please click on 'Run' button to start execution"
- step:
name: Start Execution
caches:
- maven
trigger: manual
script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
- mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
- Results/**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another image as a service and the maven test command.

```
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
default:
- step:
name: Code is pushed - Ready for Execution
script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
- echo "Please click on 'Run' button to start execution"
- step:
name: Start Execution
caches:
- maven
services:
- chrome
trigger: manual
script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
- mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose
- mvn test
artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
- Results/** 

definitions:
  services:
    chrome:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome
```

Comment: When doing it this way, what would the address of the chrome driver be? I'm getting: `Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.`